# How does ~0x00 return -1?

Tags: c, binary, bit, bitmask

As far as I know, ~0x00 equals to:
First step, change 0's to 1 and 1's to zero, Second step, add 1
Step 1: 11111111111111111111111111111 (count =32)

Step 2: 11111111111111111111111111111+1=0

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `~` operator does not perform 2's complement negation.  You can do that with the unary `-` operator (assuming your machine uses 2's complement representation).

What `~` does is invert all bits.  That's all it does, no adding 1.

Comment: But I am talking about bitmasking in c, I am really sorry I did not mention it on the description, this is my first question. When I compile ~0x00 on c complier it returns -1.

Comment: @user238795 Which is correct because `~` only inverts the bits, and a signed integer with all bits 1 has the value -1.

Comment: Ah, I am really sorry I thought inverting all bits was getting 2's complement. Thanks a lot to you both.

Comment: @user238795 What you described in the question, inverting all bits *then adding 1* is 's complement.

Comment: ***`The ~ operator does not perform 2's complement negation`*** no, it simple binary begation It does not care about something`complemet.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is correct; there is no step 2.  Unary `~` does not *negate values* (`1 => -1`), it only *inverts bits* (`0101 => 1010`).

Unary `-` negates values, and on a two's-complement system will do something very similar to your two steps.